# My join doesn't return the value at the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, join, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var announcementCat = (from p in db.announcements
                           join f in db.announcementsCategories
                           on p.kind equals f.ann_kind 
                           select new
                           {

                               kindtext = f.ann_kindtext,

                           }).ToList()
                           .Select(x => new announcements()
                           {
                               kind = x.ann_kindtext
                           });
    return View(db.announcements.OrderByDescending(announcements=> announcements.Pubdate).ToList());
}
```

And this is what I try in my View

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pubdate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @ViewBag.announcementCat
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

What I am trying is to bring the `announcement` category and not the `id`. But my code doesn't return anything and I don't get any errors. It brings all the data except the `announcement` category which is the `kindtext` field.

***EDIT***
My 1st model

```
 public class announcements
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ann_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Pubdate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int kind { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public String title { get; set; }


}
```

}

My 2nd model

```
 public class announcementsCategories
{

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "category ID")]
    public int ann_kind { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "category description")]
    public String ann_kindtext { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You create a query, but then throw it away because all you return to the view is `db.announcements.OrderBy(..)` etc (not the query). Not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: What I am trying is to bring a list with all of my announcements. It brings the the date,id  of category and the title. I have two tables announcements and announcementCategories. I join them on id. I dont want to bring the id of category but its description.May I have two return?

Comment: Still does not make sense - your query first creates anonymous objects with `ann_kind = p.kind` and `kindtext = f.ann_kindtext,` (and you repeat `ann_kind` again) - how does that relate to `date`, `category` and `title`? Then you initialize a new `announcements` and only set the `kind` property (so everything other property is `null` or its default). And then finally you ignore everything you have just done and call the database again.

Comment: If you show your models and indicate which properties of which models you want to display, then an answer can be given to solve this.

Comment: I update my question. I call date and title in my view thank you

Comment: So do you want `Pubdate` and `title` from `announcements` and `ann_kindtext` from `announcementsCategories`?

Comment: Yes you are right but I dont have any problem to bring the pubdate and the tittle. Do I have to include them in query too?

Comment: Answer added, but please check the comment in the query (very difficult to understand your code with those confusing property names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a view model to represent what you want to display in the view

```
public class AnouncementVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the GET method, project your query into the view model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = (from p in db.announcements
                join f in db.announcementsCategories
                on p.ann_ID equals f.ann_kind // note I think this needs to be - on p.kind equals f.ann_kind
                select new AnouncementVM
                {
                    Title = p.title,
                    Date = p.Pubdate,
                    Category = f.ann_kindtext 
                }).ToList();
    return View(data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
}
```

And in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<AnouncementVM>
....
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Category)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.Why do I have to declare a new model?

Comment: Because you existing model does not have a property `string Category` (or what you refer to as `ann_kindtext`) to display the name of the category.

Comment: thank you! I receive the error The entity or complex type 'MySite.Models.AnouncementVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. I have the same yesterday that why I try with anonymous select. Should I do the same?

Comment: What do you mean `MySite.Models.announcements` - the view model I gave you is `AnouncementVM` - are you using the code in my answer?

Comment: Note also (not that it really makes any difference), but you can also put the `order by` in the sql query

Answer (score 1):

Because you've missed to return the `announcementCat` to the view. You should return the join result like this:

```
ViewBag.announcementCatcode = announcementCat;
```

Then in the `View`:

```
@foreach (var item in ((List<string>)ViewBag.announcementCatcode)) 
{
    @item
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. It returns the error: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType6`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32],MySite.Models.announcements]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: Do I have to remove my foreach?

Comment: @touinta...Because I assumed that it's type is `string`. You could change the `((List<string>)ViewBag.announcementCatcode)` to `((List<int>)ViewBag.announcementCatcode)`.

Comment: What I need to bring is a string. Maybe the wrong is at the join.

Comment: @touinta...BTW the solution is: you should return the query to the view and then use `ViewBag.announcementCatcode`. Maybe the problem is with your join query. Make sure that query is returned what you want and then do what I said and get the result in view.